# Calculate the convenience index based on distance and price

Tags: real-analysis, statistics

Now, this is probably a very simple problem, but I've been trying and didn't get to a good solution.

Say that there is the need of renting a house near a place, and we have a list of candidates. Of these houses we know their price per day and the distance from this place. What I would want to calculate is some kind of "convenience index", basically if an house costs less and has less distance (from the place) it will have a greater value, if costs more and it is more distant (from the place), it will have a lower value.

[Something like this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t8sR.png)

Comment: It depends on how convenient money and distance are to you.  You could multiply them together, and take the reciprocal (perhaps multiplying by some big constant to get sensibly scaled results).  The effect would be that something half the price would be twice as convenient and something half the distance would also be twice as convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need some kind of weighted average. Pick two numbers $a$ and $b$ and calculate
$$
\text{inconvenience} = a \times \text{ cost } + b \times \text{ distance }.
$$
The larger the value the less good the house. The larger $a$ is relative to $b$ the more cost matters compared to distance. You will have to pick values for $a$ and $b$ that make sense in context.